# Write a query with inner join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

Client (
ID_Client INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Gender varchar(25),
Age INT
)

Product (
ID_Product INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Product_name varchar(255),
Product_type varchar(255)
)

Client_Product (
ID_Client INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID_Product INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUKT(ID_PRODUKTU),
Open_Date DATE
)

I need to write query that will count how many women have a specific product e.g."chair" in each age group. Sort results in descending order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following.  I made the assumption that the value for the gender column would be 'FEMALE' but, of course, you can change if I guessed wrong (e.g. if it should be 'WOMAN').

```
DECLARE @ProductName VARCHAR(255);
SET @ProductName='CHAIR';

SELECT Client.Age, COUNT(*) AS ProductCount 
FROM Product
JOIN Client_Product ON Product.ID_Product=Client_Product.ID_Product
JOIN Client ON Client_Product.ID_Client=Client.ID_Client
WHERE Product.Product_name=@ProductName
AND Client.Gender='FEMALE'
GROUP BY Client.Age
ORDER BY ProductCount DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).